# why sometimes i have xhr reques [NETWORK ERROR CHANGED] error?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, xmlhttprequest

I have a SPA developed in VUE, I installed it on my server a few months ago. Everything was fine until a few days ago. The thing is that randomly some requests are returned with `failed NETWORK_CHANGED` status. And then you reload the page and some requests are successful and some are not. Can you please tell me what could be the reason? Can the reason be in DNS. I will be very grateful for any answer, thank you